# Android Update toolbar/actionbar title from Adapter

Tags: android, android-actionbar, adapter

How can I update ActionBar title from Adapter?

I tried this:

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.home_item));
```

but this way only works within fragments. So I do this:

```
((MainActivity) view.getContext()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.home_item));
```

and get cast exception. I don't know how to do it.

So it is possible to update ActionBar Title from Adapter? Thanks

Comment: Pass instance of actionBar and activity to the adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the activity context in your adapter.

```
Myadapter adapter = new Myadapter (this);
```

In Myadapter class:

```
Context context;
public Myadapter(Context c){
      this.context = c;
}
```

Now use `context` to set the title like:

```
((MainActivity) context.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.home_item));
```

Comment: Hi rafsanahmad007, when I pass the context, in your way or other way I get "clascastexception". I dont konw why! I can not update toolbar title from adapter. Thank u for your help!

Comment: `clascastexception` post the full logcat errror?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                                                                          java.lang.ClassCastException: com.agustinherrerocola.motogpmanager.activity.PilotsMotoGPActivity cannot be cast to com.agustinherrerocola.motogpmanager.activity.MainActivity
                                   at com.agustinherrerocola.motogpmanager.adapter.PilotsAdapter

Comment: I think the problem is that I pass the Application context and I should pass the Activity context. I have tried this: pass the activity context in my adapter public PilotsAdapter(Context context, List<Pilots> items) {
        this.items = items;
        this.mContext = context;
    } but doesnt work

Comment: the reason for class cast exception is that your activities do not match...use this instead `((PilotsMotoGPActivity) context.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.home_item));`

Comment: Thank you rafsanhmad007! I will try in a moment! I will write you with the test solution

Comment: Ok. I am going to try to explain you. The title Toolbar I wanted to chage is in the ActivityMain, not in PilotsMotoGPActivity! With your solution I update the title toolbar PiltotsMotoGPActivity (so is good to you, well done). But, I wanted to change the Toolbar title of the MainActivity. You know how can I do it? I appreciate your help. Regards.

Comment: I just have accepted your answer as the most useful! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like a callback structure? With this you don't need to pass an instance of your whole `Context` but just the callback.

```
class Adapter{
  private AdapterCallback callback;
  public Adapter(AdapterCallback callback){
    this.callback = callback;
  }

  public interface AdapterCallback{
   void changeTitle(String s);
  }
}
```

And your Activity implements `AdapterCallback` and pass it to the Adapter like

```
    class YourActivity extends Activity implements AdapterCallback{

    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this);

    public void changeTitle(String s){
      getSupportActionBar().setTitle(s);
    }     
}
```

With that you can simply call in your Adapter class

```
callback.changeTitle("New Title");
```

Comment: Hi Murat, I have tried to do that but I had gotten "Nullpointerexception". Doesnt work. Thank u for your help anyway.