# Updating Toolbar subtitle from adapter class Android

Tags: java, android, adapter

I'm trying to update the subtitle of my toolbar from an adapter class. I've tried the accepted answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42788882/android-update-toolbar-actionbar-title-from-adapter).

```
((OrderActivity) context.getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Bla Bla"));
```

Order Activity is the calling activity and this line of code is in the adapter. The context being used here is passed from the calling/parent activity.

I'm getting a 'cannot resolve method getSupportActionBar()'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `((OrderActivity) context).getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Bla Bla");`